# Document text missing newlines in MS-Word

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I want to get the document text in a word document for further processing, but the text read from document is missing newlines and words are squashed together.
Here's a test case. First, writing a couple of lines to a new document:

```
PS C:\Users\outlo> $wordInstance = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
PS C:\Users\outlo> $wordInstance.Visible = $true
PS C:\Users\outlo> $doc = $wordInstance.Documents.Add()
PS C:\Users\outlo> $sel = $wordInstance.Selection
PS C:\Users\outlo> $sel.TypeText("Hello World!")
PS C:\Users\outlo> $sel.TypeParagraph()
PS C:\Users\outlo> $sel.TypeText("Hello World 2!")
PS C:\Users\outlo> $doc.SaveAs("saved.doc", [microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatDocument)
```

And now reading:

```
PS C:\Users\outlo> $wordInstance = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
PS C:\Users\outlo> $wordInstance.Visible = $true
PS C:\Users\outlo> $wordInstance.Documents.Open("C:`\Users`\outlo`\Documents`\saved.doc")
PS C:\Users\outlo> $allText = $doc.StoryRanges[1].Text
PS C:\Users\outlo> $allText
Hello World!Hello World 2!
```

The newline in the middle is missing. I'm using Word 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by first saving the document as `.txt` with newlines enabled then reading that text.

```
$txtPath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($docPath, '.txt')
$doc.SaveAs2($txtPath, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatTextLineBreaks)
$wordInstance.Quit()
$allText = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($txtPath)
```